# Ocamldoc "Unbound module Thread" without ocamlfind

Tags: multithreading, ocaml, ocamldoc

Is it possible to use ocamldoc for a project with Threads without using ocamlfind? More importantly, how?

`-thread` or `-package` aren't supported by ocamldoc, and `-I -thread` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `-thread` or `-package` aren't supported by ocamldoc, and *`-I -thread`* doesn't work.

Try with `-I +threads` instead. This will tell `ocamldoc` where to look for the thread library files.

On a side note, I use `ocamlbuild` for generating documentation, when I am already using it for my project builds (which is most of the time). With this tool, you only need to list all the documented ml files in a single `.odocl` file, and ask for the corresponding `.docdir/index.html` with the same parameters as a compilation command to get the documentation generated. If your project *compiles* with `ocamlbuild`, it should be able to generate documentation without hiccups with it as well.

```bash
$ ls src
foo.ml bar.ml baz.zip
$ ls -1 src/*.ml | cut -f1 -d'.' > project.odocl
$ cat project.odocl
src/foo
src/bar

$ ocamlbuild project.docdir/index.html
[...]
$ ls project.docdir
Bar.html
Foo.html
index.html
[...]
```

Comment: I meant it without ocamlfind (hence ocamlbuild) because it is not meant for me. Thanks though!

Comment: Ocamlbuild doesn't necessarily use ocamlfind. I have a couple of projects using threads and built with ocamlbuild, and they don't require ocamlfind AFAIK (though ocamlfind is a nice tool to have).